# pip installation, how should I add include and lib directories on windows?

Tags: python, python-2.7

pip installation on python2.7/Windows 10 fails with **fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file:**

I tried below commands in command line

```
set INCLUDE=C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenSSL-Win32\include;%INCLUDE%
set LIB=C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenSSL-Win32\lib;%LIB%
```

also, I tried adding these lines into vcvarsall.bat in

```
C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\vcvarsall.bat
```

I even tried

```
pip install --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-Ic:\Program Files (x86)\OpenSSL-Win32\include\openssl" cryptography-2.4.2.tar.gz
```

,but I always get following error

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'openssl/opensslv.h'
```

What am I doing wrong here?  How can I make this include directory recognized?

All the files are in place SSL (**Win32OpenSSL-1_1_1a**) has been installed already.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with following line

```
pip install --global-option="build_ext" --global-option="-Ic:\Program Files (x86)\OpenSSL-Win32\include" --global-option="-Lc:\Program Files (x86)\OpenSSL-Win32\Lib" cryptography-2.4.2.tar.gz
```

I just had to be more careful with parameter formatting.

Comment: In particular, about being careful with formatting - don't put `-I` and `-L` in a single `--global-option`.